# Yammer API Groups/Users in Group only being returned for 1 network

Tags: api, rest, yammer

My goal is to get a count of users in each group returned from the Yammer Data Export API. The list of groups that is returned from the data export api belong to roughly 15 networks. When querying the endpoints listed below, I am getting results back for the 1 main network, but not for the other 14. Are there any known limitations for the REST API in regards to accessing data for some of the networks returned from the data export API. In other words, there is information provided in the data export API, but when trying to expand on that information using the REST API, nothing is returned.

https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/groups/{group_id}.json

https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users/in_group/{group_id}.json

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any known limitations for the REST API in regards to
>   accessing data for some of the networks....

By design, the access token (that you're using in your code) is tied to ONLY one network and that explains why you can ONLY get results from ONLY that network.